# pycharm :::: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess, face-recognition

```
def login(self):
    unkonw_img_path='./.tmp.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(unkonw_img_path,self.most_recent_capture_arr)
    output = subprocess.check_output(['face_recognition', self.db_dir,unkonw_img_path])
    print(output)
    os.remove(unkonw_img_path)
```

error pycharm :

```
 in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

login face_recognition

Comment: Looks like it couldn't find the `face_recognition` executable program.  Is it installed on your computer?  Can you run that program yourself in a command window?

Comment: This line of code has an error 
output = subprocess.check_output(['face_recognition', self.db_dir,unkonw_img_path])

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Yes, you already posted that error in the question.  I'm confused why you would post it again in a comment, instead of answering my question...

Comment: yes face_recognition  model install pycharm

Comment: I still don't understand.  What does "face_recognition model install pycharm" mean?  That's gibberish.

Comment: face_recognition installed . but this error showing :  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ face_recognition C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\fac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (face_recognition:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: That error says that the `face_recognition` program is NOT installed.  Or perhaps it was installed, but wasn't added to the `PATH` environment variable.